# find character with regular expression except listed items

Tags: regex, filter, htmlspecialchars

I'm stuck on a regular expression. I have tons of text which is full of

```
 `&amp; , &nbsp; , &lt... e.t.c.`
```

I need a regexp which will find all `&`-s  that are not part of listed items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the language, but you might use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
&(?!\#?\w+;)
```

This should take care of named entities (`&pi;`) and numbered entities (`&#34;`);

Comment: Well thanks for answer but this will find all html special characters, i need any phrase that contains `&` symbol but is not start of html special character like `&amp;`

by the way i'm using notepad++ to search in my code files.

Comment: @Konstantin - I'm not sure I understand... Can you please edit the question, and explain what you're trying to do, possible with input/output examples?

Comment: @Kobi, I think Notepad++ does not support lookaheads.

Comment: @stema - That would be most unfortunate.

Comment: ow i'm sorry i didn't noticed `&` in the start of your regexp.
unfortunately it doesn't works in notepad++ but i'll better find another text editor 
One more time thanks.

Comment: @Konstantin - it was a `$` for a few minutes, but I fixed it promptly. Sorry `:P`